# How many confirmed kills does Wedge Antilles have?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, kill-count

I have been rereading some of my favorite Legends Star Wars books and it occurs to me... Wedge Antilles has a *lot* of kills. It seems that he consistently is getting multiple kills in every engagement in each of the books and he is in a lot of books.

I understand that many of these are in non-Disney canon and am interested in both types of sources.

- How many confirmed kills does Wedge Antilles have (broken out by type of kill and what ship he was in, if possible) and what sources were those from?

I have searched a fair bit online and gotten nothing, just "a lot." I am sure the number is significant..

<sub>Bonus points if you add in other Rogue Squadron folks like Wes Janson, Tycho Celchu, Corran Horn, etc.</sub>

Comment: It's going to be a chore to calculate this, but not impossible lol. If you want stats on the rest of Rogue Squadron, either ask in separate questions or modify this question. It won't be flagged as too broad, though I suggest you should specify exactly which pilots you want.

Comment: This will be more than a chore, checking across all 9 X-Wing books plus whichever other books he's in, and the original trilogy. This is pretty much asking for someone to go through every book line by line searching for kills. I am very interested, but it might be asking a lot. Maybe a bounty would be suitable as a reward in this case. Still good question, but dam.

Comment: one of the x-wing books which i forget mentions changing his kill count to base 16 (due to his alien technician)

Comment: @NeilNorris i'm pretty sure they change the counting base so that he still can have all his kills shown on his x-wing, since every pilot gets a little painting of every ship he destroyed and Wedge killed many imperials (not to forget the two deathstars painted on his x-wing). But neither do i remember in which of the x-wing books it is nor if it states how many are painted there

Comment: @TheBourbonKid - the don't say an exact number.  And they didn't change the counting base just to tally his kills, rather they pain some in red (as opposed to black) to represent an entire squadron's worth of kills (12 ships per red silhouette).

Answer (score 3):

Wedge Antilles has a LOT of kills as a fighter pilot, possibly more than any other pilot in the galaxy.

In the novel Rogue Squadron, by Michael Stackpole (which is Legends continuity, set between the events of Return of the Jedi and the conquest of Coruscant, between 6 and 7 ABY) Wedge takes time to inspect his X-Wing, and pauses to consider his kill markers.

While he is looking at them, his lead flight engineer (Zraii, a Verpine) mistakenly believes Wedge thinks his kills are being shorted.  He clarifies that the silhouettes painted in red are meant to indicate a squadron's worth of kills.  In the X-Wing series, a squadron of fighters is generally understood to be 12, and this is made explicit in that exchange.

The quote reads, in part:

> He paused for a moment and looked at the rows of TIE fighters, bombers, and Interceptors painted on the side of the ship.  Big Death Starts bracketed the collection of smaller ships on either side, and Ssi-ruuk fighters had started a new row

This means that Wedge has been credited (at least partially) with kills for both Death Stars, and enough snubfighters that some of them have to be grouped by the dozen.

At a conservative estimate, excluding the Death Stars, this means that he has almost certainly destroyed over 200 enemy fighters in combat.  Given that most Imperial fighters lack ejection seats, this means he has a personal kill count in the triple digits, at minimum.

Over the course of the 9 books in the X-Wing series, Wedge kills at least another dozen enemy fighters.

Wedge, however, remains active for at least another decade after the X-Wing series ends (though significant portions of that time are spent as a General or as part of Ackbar's staff, not as a pilot).

**There is no definitive, exhaustive list of Wedge's kills**.  Even if there were, it would likely be invalidated in the current canon.  In Legends canon, however, it can be safely assumed that **Wedge is credited with confirmed kills of over 200 enemy ships**.  Kills of enemy personnel aren't really counted (because it's hard to estimate how many people died on a Star Destroyer as a result of a given hit, and the fact that it's not really kosher to brag about how many people you kill, instead of how many ships you blow up).

Answer (score 0):

According to the (canon) short story [Grounded](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grounded) at the start of the Battle of Yavin Wedge is an 'ace' with nine *confirmed* kills. During that conflict, various other appearances in [Star Wars Rebels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) and his part in the Battle of Endor he splashes at least half dozen more bogies, not to mention a [Star Destroyer](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/20078364/that-still-only-counts-as-one.jpg)

> They were passing through the magnetic field. She heard Red Two (pilot: Wedge Antilles, 1,598 flight hours, **ace, nine confirmed kills**)