# How many confirmed LGBT characters have appeared in Star Wars materials?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, canon, sexuality

I know that **[Moff Delian Mors](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Delian_Mors)** (a lesbian woman in the excellent canon novel *Lords of the Sith*) is the first LGBT character in Disney canon, and **[Sinjir Rath Velus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sinjir_Rath_Velus)** (from the abominable canon novel *Star Wars:  Aftermath*) is the first gay man in Disney canon. Also in *Aftermath*, there is a lesbian couple - Esmelle and Shirene.

Another casual reference to a minor gay character referred to only as **[Ledaney](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ledaney)** appears in the brilliant *Star Wars: Bloodline*:

> “You sure you’re doing okay over there, Seastriker?” shouted Ledaney, who was fixing up his own X-wing a few meters away. “Or do we need to fetch you some soda water and a fan?”
>
> Guffaws echoed from every pilot in the place. Joph had made the mistake of being honest about his reaction to Port in a Storm, which meant he was going to spend the whole day hearing about it from guys who’d never once tried drinking the stuff.
>
> So he shot back, “I’m good, Ledaney. But what about you? Word has it you’ve been hitting the Corellian stuff pretty hard lately.”
>
> This time the laughter was louder. Anybody who didn’t know Ledaney would assume Joph was talking about the famed brandy, **but every pilot in the squadron knew Ledaney’s new man was from Corellia.**
>   -  *Star Wars:  Bloodline* by Claudia Gray

And unofficial though his statement was, Oscar Isaac attracted attention when he said he played the part of Poe as though Poe was romantically interested in Finn:

> “I think it’s very subtle romance that’s happening; you have to watch it a few times to see the little hints. At least I was playing romance; in the cockpit I was playing romance."
>   -  [Oscar Isaac on *Ellen*](https://youtu.be/fuAwgmz7jTc?t=2m18s)

Similarly, Mark Hamill said Luke's sexuality is in the eye of the beholder:

> “If you think Luke is gay, of course he is."
>   -  [Mark Hamill, quoted in *Time Magazine*](https://time.com/4247888/mark-hamill-says-luke-skywalker-could-be-gay/)

However, Mors, Velus, and Ledaney are canonically LGBT characters, but Luke and Poe's sexual orientations are as yet unknown.

#### Are there other characters in the franchise who are confirmed to be LGBT?

*Note:  Although I'm not aware of any pre-Disney LGBT characters, and I'm primarily interested in Disney canon, Legends is acceptable as well.*

Comment: I believe the Cathar woman in KotOR will develop a crush on you if you play as a female.

Comment: [Goran Beviin and Medrit Vasur](http://www.karentraviss.com/page22/files/Is_it_true_that_some_of_the_Man.html) from *Legacy of the Force* circa 2006.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is not a *bad* question. While related to a somewhat sensitive and controversial real-world issue, it is no worse than questions such [How many people have undergone carbon freezing in Star Wars?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126236/how-many-people-have-been-undergone-carbon-freezing-in-star-wars?rq=1) and [How many confirmed kills does Wedge Antilles have?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121347/how-many-confirmed-kills-does-wedge-antilles-have?rq=1).

Comment: In a universe with such a huge array of different intelligent species it seems strange to talk about LGBT characters. I'm not well read in many of the canon sources, but I don't think the gender and sexuality of other species is mentioned very often, if at all. In which case, why not apply Mark Hamill's view of Luke to any character? "If you think Jar Jar is gay, of course he is."

Comment: 102 characters here link
Both in legends and canon
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:LGBTQ%2B_individuals

Comment: Do members of hermaphroditic species like the Hutts count as LGBT?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Not many

LGBT representation in *Star Wars*, as in much “children’s” fiction until recently, has been sparse. Of the many thousands of characters that have appeared in canon and Legends materials, only  a handful have been gay or lesbian (far less than the expected proportion), and transgender representation is arguably nonexistent. [This article](https://www.thewrap.com/lgbt-star-wars-characters-a-brief-history/) gives a rundown of the LGBT characters that had appeared at the time of writing. Aside from those mentioned in the question, we have several examples:

- Goran Beviin appeared in "Boba Fett: A Practical Man" and in *Legacy of the Force*. In the latter work, it was revealed that he was married to a man, Medrit Vasur.
- As mentioned in the question, there are minor and major lesbian and gay characters in *Star Wars: Aftermath*, such as Esmelle, Shirene, and Sinjir. However, there is another reference to two more gay or bisexual characters, though it be exceedingly brief. Iggs’s parents are both male:

  > “What happened to your parents?” the woman asks.
  >
  > Iggs freezes. He doesn’t want to think about it or even say it. He
  >   tries to block out the memories of seeing his two fathers lying there
  >   like that…
  >
  > —*Star Wars: Aftermath*
- Some have argued that Ziro the Hutt, from the *Clone Wars* TV series, is gay (and perhaps a stereotypical representation thereof). However, the main piece of evidence for this seems to be that his manner of speaking [apparently](https://www.moviefone.com/2008/08/13/is-there-really-a-gay-hutt-in-star-wars-the-clone-wars/) was based on that of the (gay) Truman Capote. As indicated in the linked article, David Filoni, director of *The Clone Wars*, asserts that the Hutts generally have a fluid sexuality, and perhaps gender:

  > He’s of questionable [sexuality] at least as a slug. They tell me that
  >   these slugs can be either male or female depending. That’s something I
  >   guess that slugs and snails do. I wasn’t aware of that but I have
  >   continuity experts that tell me these things.

  I suppose Jabba is the exception? He seems fairly clearly heterosexual. In any case, if the majority of the Hutts are of fluid sexuality or gender, the whole species could be considered (*very* oblique) LGBT representation.
- Tantagru Motts-Danel, a noted artist and propagandist, was a male Tarnab married to a male Weequay.

  > TANTAGRU MOTTS-DANEL: A sandscribe from a Tarnab colony on Sriluur,
  >   **Tantagru Motts-Danel and his Weequay husband, Gojuni Motts-Danel**, were
  >   a notable couple in the corporate art scene, specializing in
  >   holography and abstract art.
  >
  > <sub>*Star Wars Propaganda: A History of Persuasive Art in the Galaxy*</sub>

  This is also notable as one of the few canonical examples of interspecies marriages in *Star Wars*, and perhaps the *only* canon instance of a hyphenated surname.

A few Star Wars video games also have featured LGBTQ characters.

- In *Knights of the Old Republic*, Juhani is lesbian. As [noted](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Juhani) on Wookieepedia:

  > Juhani is the first female character written for the Star Wars
  >   universe that is a lesbian. An error in the first release of the video
  >   game allowed player-characters of both male and female genders to
  >   access the Juhani romance sub-plot, leading some people to believe
  >   that Juhani was bisexual, but the error has since been corrected and
  >   the romance sub-plot restricted to female player-characters. Juhani’s
  >   romance sub-plot is still available to male player-characters via
  >   fan-made mods and is still noted as accessible to all
  >   player-characters on her Databank entry.
- Similarly, in *Star Wars: The Old Republic*, characters can form same-sex pairings, [albeit](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/gamesblog/2013/jan/25/star-wars-old-republic-gay-planet) only on a single planet:

  > But for some reason, the nature of those relationships was limited to
  >   heterosexual interaction only – an odd decision from a studio that has
  >   featured same-sex relationships in its Mass Effect and Dragon Age
  >   titles. Immediately, the team announced that it would be updating its
  >   romantic content, but early in January, the game’s executive producer,
  >   Jeff Hickman warned that this was going to be a complex process, and
  >   hinted that compromises would be necessary. And the compromise is
  >   Makeb, the gay planet, available only via download – and the only
  >   place in the galaxy where relationships can be formed with NPCs of the
  >   same gender.

---

I am not aware of any definite transgender characters in *Star Wars*. 
 [The article](https://www.thewrap.com/lgbt-star-wars-characters-a-brief-history/) mentioned earlier talks about Reess Kairn, who did indeed change *sex*. However, since this was done for utilitarian purposes, it is highly uncertain whether Reess’s gender is male or female. Thus Reess cannot be said to definitively count as a transgender character.

Comment: SWTOR put LGBT stuff in so it won't discriminate, but it did exactly that since M2M relationships are possible within the game while F2F ones are not !  So it's an epic fail of an attempt, practically.

Comment: @Overmind - Eh, an imperfect attempt is better than no attempt at all, in my opinion.

Comment: How can anyone actually realize something if all they do is attempt ?

Comment: Ziro had a relationship with the female [Sy Snootles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sy_Snootles).

Comment: Historical aside: SWTOR had/has no same-gender romances in its launch content. After launch, there was an editorial change, and all content since then that includes new romances has made them available to both genders of player. But it's never been feasible from a design or economics standpoint to go back and change the initial content, hence the odd dichotomy. (Also, there was in fact a bisexual woman in the Makeb storyline, on the Republic side.)

Comment: There is also an enby side character in the Aftermath trilogy, the pirate Eleodie who uses the pronouns zhe/zher.  And the novel Resistance Reborn also has a side lesbian couple and a guy with a male ex.  And Doctor Aphra of the titular series is explicitly gay, having dated two different women onscreen - Tolavn and Sana Starros, the latter who is bi.

Comment: @Sophie - Yes, this is a very old answer. As you say, some explicitly gay, bisexual, lesbian and nonbinary characters have been added to non-central works, but I have not kept up with the series for a while, although I was aware of Doctor Aphra. An updated answer to this question would be ideal.

Comment: Ah gotcha, my first thought was just of the other Aftermath characters and Aphra.  I don't have the quotes on hand so I don't know if I could put together a full answer, but it is nice to see that the list has expanded since this answer.

Comment: @Sophie - Right, no pressure! I have put a bounty on the question to attract a more updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Amilyn Holdo from *The Last Jedi* implied that she could be open to more than just humanoids (and, less explicitly, males).

> "A pair of pretty dark eyes." Then Amilyn thought about that for a moment. "Or more than a pair, if you're into Grans. Or Aqualish, or Talz. Or even - "
>
> "That's all right! Leia said through laughter. "It's just humanoid males for me."
>
> "Really? That feels so limiting."
>
> "Thank goodness it's a big galaxy."
>
> <sub><sup>[Leia: Princess of Alderaan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leia,_Princess_of_Alderaan)</sup></sub>

Comment: I don't see anything in this that suggests that she's bisexual. It certainly implies that she's willing to have (ahem) relations with aliens.

Comment: I don't think bisexual is the right word. Here on little old Earth, we have the terms "omnisexual" and "pansexual" to reflect people who don't limit their partnerships along gender or sexuality lines. However, we only have one sapient species. Is there even a term for somebody who's willing to cross species boundaries in a setting where there are multiple sapient forms of life?

Comment: @Valorum she did say that in response to Leia being attracted to only “humanoid **males**”

Comment: @T.J.L. I think "xenophile" is common, although it's a rather ambiguous usage.

Comment: @CorvoAttano - She said it in response to her saying that she only liked "**humanoid** males".

Comment: @CorvoAttano: Xenosexual.

Answer (score 4):

Reddit user Bond_SWLibriComics created this helpful guide of every LGBTQIA+ character in the current canon. I'll provide more information below.

[image: A poster titled "Star Wars LGBTQIA+ Characters". On top the Millennium Falcon flies past, leaving a rainbow trail. The characters are represented by their stylised heads and are all enumeratd below.]

- Ackmena - [A woman married to another woman](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Kloo_Horn_Cantina_Caper)
- Aleksin and Pavol - [Married men](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lando_1)
- Holdo - [Unconcerned with gender or species](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leia,_Princess_of_Alderaan)
- Yu and Just Lucky - [Male partners](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Aphra_(2020)_8)
- Cryar and Marcy - [Female partners](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/File:CassieCryar_IoneMarcy_PabloHidalgo_tweet.png). [Marcy also had a male partner in the past.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_Lost)
- Bog and Posla - [Male partners](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Aphra_(2016)_15)
- Ceret - [Non-binary](https://instagram.com/p/CNFwI8oFhR-)
- Wilsorr - [A man in a relationship with another man](https://instagram.com/p/CNFwI8oFhR-)
- Aphra - [Confirmed](https://www.starwars.com/news/doctor-aphra-creator-kieron-gillen-co-writer-si-spurrier-discuss-whats-next-for-the-fan-favorite-rogue) to be a lesbian. Had relationships with the women [Okka](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Aphra_(2020)_2), [Starros](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Aphra:_An_Audiobook_Original), and [Tolvan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Aphra_(2016)_15), respectively. [Starros also had relationships with men.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_6)
- Hansen - [A gay male](https://www.starwars.com/news/doctor-aphra-creator-kieron-gillen-co-writer-si-spurrier-discuss-whats-next-for-the-fan-favorite-rogue)
- Flix and Orka - [Male partners](https://web.archive.org/web/20191001213059/https://www.coffeewithkenobi.com/cwk-show-298-star-wars-resistance-season-two-press-day-coverage/)
- Sy - [Non-binary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_High_Republic:_Race_to_Crashpoint_Tower)
- Venzee - [Non-binary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Squadrons)
- Calrissian - [Pansexual](https://web.archive.org/web/20180625075307/https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/lando-calrissian-sexual-fluidity-solo-star-wars_us_5af77d59e4b00d7e4c1b37a9)
- Lapin - [Non-binary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Aphra_(2020)_7)
- D'Acy and Tyce - Married women. [They're the pair that kiss in *Rise of Skywalker*.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_IX_The_Rise_of_Skywalker)
- Gyasi - [Asexual](https://www.starwars.com/databank/leox)
- Tarkon and T'onga - [Female partners](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bounty_Hunters_1)
- The San Tekkas - [Married men](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_High_Republic:_Light_of_the_Jedi)
- Saché and Yanê - [Female partners](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Queen%27s_Shadow)
- Velus - [A gay man](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aftermath_(novel))
- Naberrie - [Asexual and aromantic](https://ekjohnston.tumblr.com/post/190883221572/im-hearing-some-people-say-that-sola-naberrie-in)
- Terec - [Non-binary](https://instagram.com/p/CNFwI8oFhR-)
- TK-421 and Tarkin - Males partners. I would note that [the story](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Of_MSE-6_and_Men) this relationship is contained in is of unclear canonicity. Additionally, while Tarkin's identity is implied, it is never directly stated.
- Grey - [A man married to another man](https://www.starwars.com/databank/varko-grey).
- Moradi - [Implied to be asexual and/or aromantic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy%27s_Edge:_Black_Spire)
- Quell - [A bisexual woman](https://www.starwars.com/news/marvel-star-wars-pride-month-covers)

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by primary source quotes for as many characters as possible, or quotes from interviews, indicating their genders or sexual orientations, unless the image is official.

Comment: @Adamant I've updated to include links to the text showing the identity, or it that's unavailable, a statement from a creator.

Answer (score 2):

Saché and Yamé, Padmé’s handmaidens as seen in the book ‘Queen’s Shadow’ by E. K. Johnson are in a relationship, meaning they’re either gay, bi, or pan.

Comment: Can you offer a book quote to confirm this fact?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice find, however, as per the above comment could you [edit] this to include some evidence to back this up? For example, a relevant quote from the book? You may also want to take the [tour] to learn a little about the site!

Comment: It's also worth noting that Sabe from that series is confirmed to be bisexual.

Answer (score 1):

In **Doctor Aphra: An Audiobook Original** when Dr. Aphra, Sana Starros, and Princess Leia are on Sunspot prison Princess Leia says that her first meeting with Sana was "awkward" which Dr. Aphra takes to mean romantically.

> *Leia:* "I brought you on this trip Sana, so we could move beyond the awkwardness of our initial meeting"
>
> *Dr. Aphra*: "Well that totally made my ears perk up. Was there a connection between the Princess and Sana? I never would have pegged Sana as having a thing for Princesses but then again after all the stuff I subjected her to maybe she decided it would be better to go with someone the complete opposite of her usual type."

Dr. Aphra and Sana Starros have a romantic relationship in college.

> *Sana Starros to Aphra*: "Ok, so. Collandra, Yoshi, who else are you seeing besides me?"
>
> *Chelli Lona Aphra*: "Darling, I told you its hard to keep track but I've been avoiding Collandra since she started staking out my classes waiting for me to emerge. Such a stalker. Who needs that? And Yoshi came down with the Wookiee flu right after we had our first... uh... encounter."

Yoshi's sex, gender, and species (See Admiral Holdo answer) are not mentioned.  It is also not clear if the "Wookiee flu" is capable of infecting multiple species like (or is) the [Ardroxian Flu](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ardroxian_Flu)

> In fact the whole Dr. Aphra audio book is a recording to her ex-girlfriend Sana Starros